# Extract data between special characters

Tags: regex, pandas

```
df
Out[17]: 
0       (a)[b]<c>
1    (aa)[bb]<cc>
2       (e)[f]<g>
dtype: object
```

i need to extract string between the special characters.

```
df.str.findall(r'[^[]*\[([^]]*)\]')
Out[16]: 
0     [b]
1    [bb]
2     [f]
dtype: object
```

Using this, I am able to get string between [], but I am not able to extract text between (),<>
Please help me with this.
I need output to be like:

```
0    (a)    [b]   <c>
1    (aa)   [bb]  <cc>
2    (e)    [f]   <g>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df.apply(lambda x: ' '.join(re.findall('(?<=[\W])[a-z]+(?=[\W])',x)))
```

Output

```
0       a b c
1    aa bb cc
2       e f g
```

OR

```
df.apply(lambda x: ' '.join(re.findall('[\W][a-z]+[\W]',x)))
```

Output

```
0       (a) [b] <c>
1    (aa) [bb] <cc>
2       (e) [f] <g>
```

Comment: i have updated the question, to show the output type.